# how to make variable from pattern match of macro call available afterwards?

Tags: macros, elixir

The following code has no problem:

```
      assert {:ok,
              %{
                "a" => var_a,
                 ......
              } = my_func()
      assert false === is_empty(var_a)
```

but after i use my own macro `assert_match`,  `var_a` is not available any more:

```
      assert_match({:ok,
              %{
                "a" => var_a,
                 ......
              } = my_func(), "my description")
       assert_equal(false, is_empty(var_a))
```

I got error:

```
warning: variable "var_a" does not exist ......
```

why is variable "var_a" available in `assert()`, but not in my own macro `assert_match`?
how to make `var_a` available for my own macro `assert_match`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros introduce a [hygiene](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/macros.html#macro-hygiene). Excerpt from docs:

> […] guarantees that a variable defined inside a quote won’t conflict with a variable defined in the context where that macro is expanded.

To bypass a macro hygiene, one should explicitly call [`Kernel.var!/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#var!/2) on the variable.

```elixir
defmacro assert_match do
  quote do: var!(var_a) = 42
end

[…]

assert_match()
42 = var_a
```

Comment: `var_a` is the variable obtained from pattern match when calling `assert_match (%{..., "key_a" => var_a, ...})`, and there could be many unpredictable variables from patter match, how to make them all available after calling `assert_match `?

Comment: This functionality is not exported per se. [`Kernel.var!/2`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.14.4/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L4497-L4510) removes counters and sets an explicit context for these vars. [`ex_unit` technically does the same manually](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/6f96693b355a9b670f2630fd8e6217b69e325c5a/lib/ex_unit/lib/ex_unit/assertions.ex#L631-L652).